# task scheduler - batch file - path

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I have a batch file stored on my work network. When i go manually on the target folder and open my batch file it works just fine.
Thus I wanted to put this command in my task scheduler, went on it and for its action, browsed my file, got a path Y:\ and such
However when i launch my scheduled task, i have a pop up saying windows doesn't find my bat file and my cmd writes "the path can not be found"

I believe that is because with cmd it starts naturally on the C disk, thus as it is not on the right disk, the path is not found.
A pushd to change disk from C to Y works afterwards, however i have to do that manually on cmd

My question is, how can i handle my task scheduler to launch my file without having to create a copy of my file on the local disk? I would really like it to launch the bat file stored on work network.
Thought at first to write on my bat file the pushd line but well, the file is still stored on the network haha..

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run a local batch file to map the network drive as Y

```
net use y: \\server\blah
```

Then have it call your network batch file at Y:

```
call y:\mybatch.bat
```

As task scheduler runs normally as a different user it doesn't have your drive mappings.

---

Alternatively call the batch file via it's unc path `\\server\blah\mybatch.bat` and then on the first line of the batch file pushd the unc path again

```
pushd \\server\blah\
```

Comment: is there no other way than going through a local batch first?

Comment: I've added an alternative method which might work for you.